# Solve $y'(x)^2+y(x)^2=\sec^4(x)$ for arbitrary initial value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Pretty much as it says in the title. For instance, one easily sees that $y(x)=\sec(x)$ satisfies the ODE for  initial value $y(0)=1$, but is there a way to solve the DE for an arbitrary initial value of $y(0)$?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a trigonometric parametrization of the circle equation
$$
\cos^2x\,y(x)=\sin(u(x)),
\\
\cos^2x\,y'(x)=\cos(u(x)).
$$
As a consequence of this one gets, eliminating $y$ from the derivative of the first equation,
$$
\cos(u(x))u'(x)=\cos(u(x))-2\tan(x)\sin(u(x))
\\
\iff u'(x)=1-2\tan(x)\tan(u(x)).
$$
Indeed, this has $u(x)=\frac\pi2-x$ as a solution, but it does not appear that any other solution will be of equally simple form.